# Cómo acceder a valor de un span

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

¿Alguien sabe qué es lo que está causando que cuando quiero acceder al valor de un `span` que cambia al presionar un botón, la primera vez que lo presiono su valor es una cadena vacía y a partir del segundo click obtiene el valor real?

**Código HTML:**

```
<form action="mail.php" method="GET" name="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="DOI" id="doi" /> <br /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="apa" checked> APA
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class="ieee"> IEEE
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="chicago"> CHICAGO <br />
    <input type="button" value="Referencia" class="button" id="ad" />

    <div id="referencia" >
        <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto2">
        <span id="results" ></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Código jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ad").click(function () {
        var tex= $('#texto2').val();
        $('#results').load("pagina.php?valor="+tex);
        alert($('#results').html());
    });
});
```

El módulo `pagina.php` solo contiene un `POST` que es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['valor'];
?>
```

El resultado de ejecutar el código es que la primera vez que se pulsa el botón me regresa el valor del `span` vacío o como cadena vacía, y a partir del segundo click muestra su valor original.

Comment: Estás realizando una operación de llamada `Ajax`. Esta operación es asíncrona, es decir el resto del código que viene después no espera a que se termine de leer el `PHP` para ejecutarse, por lo tanto cuando lanzas el `alert` la llamada todavía no ha recibido la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: Gracias por la resupuesta. Pero sabes como puedo hacer que se termine de leer el código php para ejecutar la llamada a ajax?

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido lo que preguntas, creo que quieres saber cómo detectar que el servidor te ha devuelto una respuesta a la petición `Ajax`. El compañero @AlfredoCebrian te ha dado la respuesta que necesitas, sólo que se le ha escapado un pequeño error en el código, lee mi comentario en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es porque no le das tiempo de que cargue.

Prueba el script como sigue, una vez que se carga pagina.php llama la funcion con el alert.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ad").click(function() {
        var tex= $('#texto2').val();
        $('#results').load("pagina.php?valor="+tex, function() {
            alert($('#results').html());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Alfredo, He modificado el código a como me lo has propuesto pero ahora el alert no aparece, sabes por qué?

Comment: @JesusRegalado, la respuesta que te ha dado @AlfredoCebrian es correcta. Solo que hay un pequeño error en el código, elimina el paréntesis que hay después de `tex`, debería quedar así `$('#results').load("pagina.php?valor="+tex, function() {`

Comment: Les comento porque he tenido problemas he creado inputs dinamicos con un span para cada valor que se crea,para cada input tengo un load que actualiza cada span  pero al poner la función que me ha dado alfredo no me arroja ningún valor o me arroja cadenas vacias

Comment: Gracias @JesusRegalado, ya corregi el código. Espero que sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias a ti! Si funciona, pero ahora tengo el mismo problema pero ahora estoy creando los span dinámicos y en un ciclo for intento acceder a su valor pero no me regresa el valor, me regresa una cadena vacía.

Comment: Necesito ver el código del ciclo para buscar la falla.

Comment: @JesusRegalado, en este caso lo mejor es abrir una nueva pregunta y si la respuesta de Alfredo Cebrián resuelve tu pregunta inicial deberías marcarla como respuesta correcta. Un saludo