# Modificar y leer span desde jquery con la function load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

espero puedan ayudarme.
Tengo problemas cuando desde jquery intendo leer el valor de un span despúes de hacer un llamado a la función load(). Los span son creados dinamicamente por javascript cada span lleva un input que también es creado dinamicamente. todos los span estan en un array y los inputs en otro array, esto con la finalidad de recorrerlos, El problema es que no puedo acceder al valor del span en el primer click al boton, a partir del segundo empieza a darme los valores.
Código javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
      var num=0;
    $("#add").click(function() {
      var div = document.createElement("input");
      div.setAttribute('id',num);
      div.setAttribute('placeholder','DOI '+ num);
      div.setAttribute('name','doi2[]');
      div.setAttribute('class','form-control');
      document.getElementById('dinamico').appendChild(div);

      var spnd = document.createElement("span");
      spnd.setAttribute('id',"span"+num);
      spnd.setAttribute('name','spndoi2[]');
      div.setAttribute('class','form-control');
      document.getElementById('dinamico').appendChild(spnd);

      var salto = document.createElement('br');
      document.getElementById('dinamico').appendChild(salto);
      num++;
    });
  });
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#verifica").click(function() {
            var doiarray = document.getElementsByName('doi2[]');
            var spndoiarray = document.getElementsByName('spndoi2[]');
            for(var i = 0; i < doiarray.length; i++){
               $('#span'+i).load("pagina.php?valor="+doiarray[i].value, function(){
               console.log($('#span'+i).text());
        });
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Código de pagina.php

```html
<?php
echo $_GET['valor'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque la función *load* es asíncrona y no puedes leer los valores del span con el índice del ciclo *for*, en vez de eso utiliza:

```
 $(this).text()
```

Comment: Gracias! Ahora funciona correctamente

Comment: @JesusRegalado, si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, por favor [acepta su respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.